# How to view elements tab and sources tab at the same time in chrome dev tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a rogue blank `<div>` getting inserted from somewhere in my code, and it is difficult to find when it is coming in.  I am using `debugger;` and stepping through the code, however, the step function is in the 'Sources' tab of chrome dev tools, and the 'Elements' tab has the view I need.   I have two screens, and have the dev tools on one screen and the page on the other, but I need to see when the div is coming through on the HTML as I step through the code, and it is quite cumbersome to switch tabs after each click.

Is there any way to accomplish this view to troubleshoot faster (maybe a second instance of dev tools? or split the tabs?), or another suggestion?   Since I don't know how it is getting generated, I can't color the div and just look for the color to come on screen...

Answer (score 11):

It is still not possible to display the elements and source tabs at the same time on chrome dev tools. (Latest Chrome version: v64).

If some element is inserted to your DOM and you want to find code responsible for adding it then I suggest using more appropriate tool than `debugger;`. Check out "[subtree modifications](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks?hl=en#debug-dom-modifications)":

[image: Break on -> subtree modifications]

Comment: Though the answer provides a solution and is accepted, it is not the exact answer to the title of the op's question. It is useful but a little incomplete makes the thread misleading in this manner. I suggest either editing the question or extending the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Now its possible to view the element and page source in the same page.

Follow the steps below:

1. Open debugger or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. From Right corner press the "customize and control Dev tools" icon, under those option click show console drawer:
   [image: show console option]
3. Now from the left bottom, click on the quick source option as shown in picture:
   [image: show quick source]
4. All the js files opened in sources will be seen here:
   [image: js files displaying as per in source tab]

Answer (score 0):

You can now right click the view tab and select "Move to bottom" so you can see both element and sources at the