# View elements tab and sources tab at the same time in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently debugging some JQuery that heavily modifies and selects DOM elements. I want to be able to see these elements change in real time rather than having to flip between the sources tab and the elements tab.

The solution posted here: [How to view elements tab and sources tab at the same time in chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735899/how-to-view-elements-tab-and-sources-tab-at-the-same-time-in-chrome-dev-tools?noredirect=1&lq=1) is unrealistic for me as I am not modifying a single dom element but rather multiple elements.

Are there any chrome extension to the developer tools that will do this? Is there another browser that will allow me to do this???

Comment: Perhaps you could use Firefox with the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension and the built-in firefox inspector/console...

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: Yep this does the trick. I'm able to have the firebug scripts tab open for stepping through my js on one monitor and the built in firefox inpector on another for seeing DOM changes. I'm surprised that chrome doesn't offer seperating tabs in the first place. Oh well, time for another monitor! Thank you very much!

Comment: Not a duplicate when the answer provided in the other thread does not answer my question. Just as the asker stated under the selected answer, this solution does allow for viewing both tabs, but it does not allow for stepping through code.

Comment: @JoshL The answer is ultimately that it isn't possible to step though at the same time as viewing any other panel in Chrome DevTools currently. To add to this, you can only have one client connected using [Chrome Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) at a time, so an extension is not possible. The fact that I couldn't provide a solution to the other question doesn't mean this isn't a duplicate issue. I'll add to my answer regarding the protocol and raise a discussion with other Chromium contributors as to the feasibility of split pane debugging.

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised this isn't a more common issue among developers.

Comment: Now possible in Chrome 87. Right click Network tab and click "Move to bottom"